# How to filter elements and hide others?

Tags: d3.js, filter

I modified some d3 filtering blocks with the intention to filter by year (ideally through a slider instead of having a button for each year) but encountered two issues:

1. upon calling filter() and exit().remove() nothing happens
2. how can i add a slider or autoplay across the years? I looked through some examples but they're a bit complex for beginner.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
          <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>D3: Loading data from a CSV file</title>
      </head>
     <body>
        <p class="s12"> select 2012 </p>
        <p class="s16"> select 2016 </p>
      <script type="text/javascript">
    
          var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
          w = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
          h = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
          var padding = 40;
          
          var data = [{
          "Food": "Apples",
          "Deliciousness": 9,
          "year": 2010
        }, {
          "Food": "Green Beans",
          "Deliciousness": 5,
          "year": 2012
        }, {
          "Food": "Egg Salad Sandwich",
          "Deliciousness": 4,
          "year": 2016
        }, {
          "Food": "Cookies",
          "Deliciousness": 10,
          "year": 2018
        } ];
    
            // format the data
            data.forEach(function(d) {
              d.Deliciousness = +d.Deliciousness;
            });
            
            
          var svg = d3.select("body")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
             .append("g")
             .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left+"," +
                     margin.top+")");
            
          var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
           .domain(d=>d.Food)
           .range([margin.left,w+margin.left])
           .paddingInner(0.2);
         xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Food; }));
    
            
          var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
           .scale(xScale)
           .ticks(5);
          
          var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
           .domain([0, d3.max(data, d=>d.Deliciousness)])
           .rangeRound([h+margin.top,margin.top]);
            
          var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
           .scale(yScale)
           .ticks(5);
          
          svg.selectAll('rect')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('x',(d,i) => margin.left + i*w/data.length)
            .attr('y',d=>yScale(d.Deliciousness))
            .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr('height',d =>h-yScale(d.Deliciousness))
            .attr('fill',function(d){
              if (d===30) return "red";
              return "rgb(0,0,"+d.Deliciousness*10+")" ;});
            
          
          svg.append("g")
           .attr("class", "axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
           .call(yAxis);
            
       svg.append("g")
           .attr("class", "axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
           .call(xAxis);
           
          d3.select(".s12")
      .on("click", function() {
      svg.selectAll("rect")
      .filter(function(d) {
        return d.year !== 2012;
      })
      .remove();
        
       d3.select(".s16")
       .on("click", function() {
       svg.selectAll("rect")
        .filter(function(d) {
          return d.year !== 2016;
        })
        .remove();  
         });
            
        
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

code updated

Comment: Are you sure the onclick function is even running? I suspect the extra space in `d3.select("p .s12")` is finding the first paragraph, then looking for any child element having class "s12" *within* the paragraph, and therefore returning nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, fix the class problem explained in the [comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517904/how-to-filter-elements-and-hide-others-in-d3#comment86042872_49517904).

Your problem here is the logic of this block:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data.filter(function(d) {
        return d.year == 2012;
    }))
    .exit().remove();
```

It makes little sense: what you're doing is filtering the data array by year (2012), which will return just **1** object. Then, you're selecting all the rectangles, binding a new data array with just one object (which will leave all the other rectangles without any data) and then calling `remove` on the exit selection. That's not correct.

Since you don't have a *new* data, just filter the selection:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .filter(function(d) {
        return d.year !== 2012;
    })
    .remove();
```

That way, you simply remove the rectangles that don't represent 2012.

This is the updated code:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  w = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  h = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var padding = 40;

var data = [{
  "Food": "Apples",
  "Deliciousness": 9,
  "year": 2010
}, {
  "Food": "Green Beans",
  "Deliciousness": 5,
  "year": 2012
}, {
  "Food": "Egg Salad Sandwich",
  "Deliciousness": 4,
  "year": 2016
}, {
  "Food": "Cookies",
  "Deliciousness": 10,
  "year": 2018
}];

// format the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Deliciousness = +d.Deliciousness;
});


var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," +
    margin.top + ")");

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d => d.Food)
  .range([margin.left, w + margin.left])
  .paddingInner(0.2);
xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.Food;
}));


var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(xScale)
  .ticks(5);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.Deliciousness)])
  .rangeRound([h + margin.top, margin.top]);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .ticks(5);

svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', (d, i) => margin.left + i * w / data.length)
  .attr('y', d => yScale(d.Deliciousness))
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr('height', d => h - yScale(d.Deliciousness))
  .attr('fill', function(d) {
    if (d === 30) return "red";
    return "rgb(0,0," + d.Deliciousness * 10 + ")";
  });


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

d3.select(".s12")
  .on("click", function() {
    svg.selectAll("rect")
      .filter(function(d) {
        return d.year !== 2012;
      })
      .remove();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<p class="s12"> select 2012 </p>
<p class="s16"> select 2016 </p>
```

Comment: this works. the previous .data(data.filter come straight from the result of google how to filter in d3.. 
but what if i don't want to leave gap and always want bar to start from leftmost? i repeated the .s12 snippet for 2016 .s16 and for some reason it doesn't work.